# Flutter при добавлении зависимости в pubspec.yaml возникает черный экран

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

У меня есть практически пустое приложение, с каким-то виджетом.

У меня к приложению в pubspec.yaml подключены зависимости:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  crypto: ^3.0.0
  firebase_core: "1.0.0"
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  dio: ^3.0.10
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  sqflite:
  intl: ^0.17.0
  translit: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  open_file: ^2.0.3


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dependency_overrides:
  # Override for `flutter_local_notifications`:
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Но стоит мне в dependencies добавить

```
file_picker: ^2.1.7
```

мое приложение перестает что-либо отображать.
Причем, во время отладки на эмуляторе/устройстве, такой проблемы нет. Она возникает во время релиза сборки приложения (Build->Flutter->Build APK) и установки его на устройство.

На всякий случай, мой Flutter Doctor:

```
E:\justDoIt\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.5.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.592], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-17.5.pre at E:\justDoIt\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 1fe38dcb5f (2 months ago), 2021-02-10 16:25:47 -0800
    • Engine revision d4453f6018
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-259.9.beta)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: E:\Program Files\Android_Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at E:\Program Files\Android_Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at E:\Program Files\IntelliJ
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • POCOPHONE F1 (mobile) • c2741f97 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема проявляется в релизной версии, то скорее всего проблема в обфускации того, что не должно. В proguard-rules.pro нужно прописать строчку:

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
```

Ну и ещё раз внимательно пройтись по установке: https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup